# 360 Video Editing in Blender?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I am trying to edit a 360 Fly Camera Video File with Blender, but experiencing difficulties.

I think I need to convert the equirectangular 2880 x 2880 video to stereographic 3840 × 1920? How can I accomplish this using Blender?

[image: Equirectangular 2880 X 2880 video file from the 360 Fly Camera]

[image: I would like to convert the 360 Fly Video to look like this Stereographic 3840 × 1920]

Comment: Its been a while since I did it, but what I did for my 360 camera was map the video clip as a texture to a slightly larger than half sphere object and render the 3D scene.